# Image is not rendering with specified width

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am facing this strange problem with an image with dimensions 500*20. The image is not rendered with a width of 500, it is rendered with a width of 50. I have tried these two approaches without any luck:

```
<Image Name="ImgSubTest" Height="20" Width="500" Canvas.Top="00" Canvas.Left="22">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="500"  
                     UriSource="/Path;component/Images/LightGreen.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

&

```
<Image Name="ImgSubTest" Height="20" Width="500" Canvas.Top="00" Canvas.Left="22"
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
       Source="/Path;component/Images/LightGreen.png" />
```

All other images in my project are rendered fine. I know I am missing something here but I am unable to figure out what.

Comment: Did you try the Stretch property? Eg: Stretch="Fill"

Comment: @mlemay:thanx,now its rendering fine, but why this happening when image is having appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the DPI setting of the image? WPF renders everything at 96DPI by default and if a PNG is not 96DPI itself WPF will render it either larger or smaller depending on it's DPI setting.

See Hanselman's article on PNG and DPI: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BeAwareOfDPIWithImagePNGsInWPFImagesScaleWeirdOrAreBlurry.aspx